# I'm getting an error of UnknownReplWriteConcern while posting in mongodb atlas using node js(express)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

Getting an error while posting data in `MongoDB` atlas.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Persons = require('./PersonsSchema');

router.post('/',async(req,res)=>{
     console.log(req.body.Name);
     console.log(req.body.Age);
try{
    const postPerson = await new Persons({

        Name : req.body.Name,
        Age : req.body.Age
    })
    const savePersons = await postPerson.save();
    res.status(200).json(savePersons)
}

catch(err){

    res.json({"err": err})
}
});


module.exports = router;
```

> And above mentioned is routed File.
>
> My data is posted in the atlas. But I am getting an error of
>   UnknownReplWriteConcern in postman while Posting a data.

My `Schema` looks like

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

 const PersonSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String },{ age: String }, {
        writeConcern: {
          w: 'majority',
          j: true,
          wtimeout: 1000
        }
      });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Persons',PersonSchema);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yesterday I face this issue, and I searched for the answer and found your question.
Recently I found the solution and it worked in my code so I decided to share it with you. So, If someone facing the same issue will get the proper solution by this answer.

Before we move to the answer, Let's understand what things are going on with write concern.

The default write concern in MongoDB has been `w:1` from as far back as MongoDB 2.2 in 2012.

There are three different settings you can use to set up write concern in current MongoDB versions (version 3.2.6 and newer):

- **`w` setting**: how many nodes should acknowledge the write before declaring it a success. The default is 1, meaning the primary node's acknowledgment is sufficient.
- **`j` setting**: do the writes must be journaled before acknowledged? Default depends on `writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault`.
- [**writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault): if you specify `w:majority` write concern setting for your writes without setting `j`, what is the implied `j` value? Default is `true` (writes should be journaled in the majority of the voting nodes before it is acknowledged).

There is also a [`wtimeout` setting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/#wtimeout) to configure how long MongoDB should wait for write concern to be satisfied before informing the client that the write has not been acknowledged. Otherwise, writes waiting for write concern to be satisfied can wait forever instead of failing.

The special setting here is `w:majority`. This means that writes must propagate to the **majority of voting nodes** (and also to their journals) in a replica set to be acknowledged. This is arguably the safest setting while providing good performance, because:

- It prevents acknowledged writes to be rolled back in the event of failures.
- It regulates the application's throughput so that it won't send writes faster than what the replica set can handle (due to hardware constraints, network situation, etc.).

As you have imagined, **voting nodes do include the arbiter**. Thus, in a replica set with primary-secondary-arbiter setup, `w:majority` could fail in a scenario where:

- One of the data-bearing node is offline for some reason.
- The replica set is still online with a writable primary since the topology is now primary-arbiter-offline.
- Writes with `w:1` will succeed as usual, but those writes could be rolled back (since it was not written to the majority of voting-data-bearing nodes).
- Since the arbiter carries no data, `w:majority` writes will fail (or waits indefinitely) since the arbiter is counted as a voting node.

For this reason, using an arbiter is not recommended if you plan to use `w:majority` in your application.

Please note that using an arbiter in a 3-node replica set that forms a shard in a sharded cluster is also not recommended since chunk moves require `w:majority`. Having a data-bearing node failure in one shard will be detrimental to chunk migration operations.

So this is the basic explanation of what is going on with write concern, 
To Fix the error you are facing, you only need to remove the `w: 'majority'` from the schema.

Like this

```
 const PersonSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String },{ age: String }, {
        writeConcern: {
          j: true,
          wtimeout: 1000
        }
      });
```

This setting has fixed my `UnknownReplWriteConcern` error and worked splendidly. So hope it would help you too.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I had MongoDB URL in the .env file When I took it out of .env into the server file things worked, vuex state could update and the error walked away. I don't know how to fix this. Having db connection url in the server file is not good practice as rather we should process it using process.env.DB_URL

Comment: Yeah, this fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

my DB_URL was in `.env` file like `DB_URL = "full_url"`. I got the same error but when I removed the quotation("") it works fine. `DB_URL = full_url` without quotation .

Comment: Even when I remove the quotations the problem still happens, so I just removed the DB_URL from the .env file and it works.

Comment: then how will you protect your DB_URL??

Comment: Okay, nevermind, it was a formatting issue, there should be no spaces and no quotations. So, it should be like this: `DB_URL=yoururlhere`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but mine was because I had an extra space at the end of the connection uri, which was affecting the ending (w=majority )

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30702356)

Answer (score 0):

?retryWrites=true&w=majorityv
remove this from mongo db URL
and use async

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same issue and found a solution that worked in my code.

previous code:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS, ( ) => {
    console.log("mongodb connected")
})
```

working code:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, ( ) => {
    console.log("mongodb connected")
})
```

Previously I forgot to specify the following boolean arguments

```
{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}
```

after updating the code with these arguments code is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

In my case simply removing the  `?retryWrites=true&w=majority` bit from the DB's URI link and replacing it with my DB's name fixed the error.

For reference the default link looks like this
`mongodb+srv://username:<password>@cluster0.drr9nzg.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

My link looks like this `'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.drr9nzg.mongodb.net/' + dbName`

*I am using mongoose to connect to MongoDB from my application running on localhost*