# How to remedy "UnknownReplWriteConcern" MongoDB Error from React Client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-native

When I am hitting my API from my React native client the code gives me this error of Mongodb.

```
LOG
{
  "error": {
    "code": 79,
    "codeName": "UnknownReplWriteConcern",
    "errInfo": {
      "writeConcern": [Object]
    },
    "result": {
      "$clusterTime": [Object],
      "electionId": "7fffffff000000000000011b",
      "n": 1,
      "nModified": 1,
      "ok": 1,
      "opTime": [Object],
      "operationTime": [Object],
      "writeConcernError": [Object]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix this problem with my code? when I hit the API from my Postman it not give me any error in Postman and the code works just fine but the issue with coming when I hit the code from the client also yesterday it was also giving the error in Postman but today it's not why it's giving me these errors I found some posts talking about the Monogo connection problem

.env:

```
MONGO_URL = 'mongodb+srv://user:pasword@database1.dbhn5us.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

Db connection:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

export const MongoDBConnection = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
        console.log('Connected to database');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error connecting to database: ' + err);
    }
};
```

Comment: Anything useful for you in [this question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61525058/1409374)?